# libexpat1-dev and libgtk2.0-dev

Tags: apt

I am trying to install `lablgtk` via the following:

`opam install lablgtk`

It gives me following error:

```
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build lablgtk 2.18.11
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed

<><> lablgtk.2.18.11 troubleshooting ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
=> This package requires gtk+ 2.0 development packages installed on your system

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please
make sure they are installed before retrying:
    libexpat1-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

I tried this:
`sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev`
but it says that
`libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.32-1ubuntu1).`

Also similar thing happens for:
`sudo apt-get install -y libexpat1-dev` where I get `libexpat1-dev is already the newest version (2.2.5-3ubuntu0.2).`

I tried both on *Ubuntu 18.04LTS and 20.04LTS*. Any suggestion what could be the solution?

Complete output:

```
  ∗ install lablgtk 2.18.11

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[lablgtk.2.18.11] found in cache

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] The compilation of lablgtk failed at
        "/home/user/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ./configure
        --prefix /home/user/.opam/default
        LABLGLDIR=/home/user/.opam/default/lib/lablgl".

#=== ERROR while compiling lablgtk.2.18.11 ====================================#
# context     2.0.7 | linux/x86_64 |  | https://opam.ocaml.org#87778c51
# path        ~/.opam/default/.opam-switch/build/lablgtk.2.18.11
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ./configure --prefix /home/user/.opam/default LABLGLDIR=/home/user/.opam/default/lib/lablgl
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/lablgtk-32104-d0f245.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/lablgtk-32104-d0f245.out
### output ###
# [...]
# checking whether C compiler accepts -fno-unwind-tables... yes
# checking platform... Unix
# checking native dynlink... checking for pkg-config... /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pkg-config
# checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.0.0... Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
# Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
# to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
# No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
# no
# *** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
# *** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
# *** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
# configure: error: GTK+ is required



<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build lablgtk 2.18.11
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed

<><> lablgtk.2.18.11 troubleshooting ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
=> This package requires gtk+ 2.0 development packages installed on your system

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please
make sure they are installed before retrying:
    libexpat1-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: Try to see where `opam` expects those installed packages. Some build systems have defaults that do not match those of the host system and they might need a little help (a flag, a symlink, ... to find the dependencies.

Comment: Can you please guide how to check that?